# Perl to read each lines and print the output in email (html)

Tags: html, perl

The below code able to read the content of file and print the content of body with the file's content.

```
use strict;     
my $filename = '.../text.txt';
open (my $ifh, '<', $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
local $/ = undef;
my @row = (<$ifh>)[0..9];
close ($ifh);
print  "@row\n";

my ($body) = @_;
my ($html_body)= @_;
.
.
.
print(MAIL "Subject: Important Announcement \n");
.
.
.
push(@$html_body, "<h1><b><font color= red ><u>ATTENTION!</u></b></h1></font><br>");
 push(@$html_body, "@row");
.
.
.
 print(MAIL "$body", "@$html_body");
 close(MAIL);
```

But unfortunately, i am having problem to produce the email body with same format of the text.txt file. The output email produced only having single line instead of paragraphs of 3.

Comment: It's not clear what the `$body` and `$html_body` variables are supposed to start out with. You are assigning the first argument to a function to both of them. But it doesn't look like you are in a function.

Comment: $body and $htnl_body assigned to list in which will develop the email.

Comment: No. Your code is full of mistakes. What do you think `@_` is for? In `push(@$html_body, "@row");` you are stringifying `@row`. That's essentially the same as `push @$html_body, join( $, , @row)`. I don't think that is what you mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that plain text contains no formatting information when placed inside a HTML document. End of line characters are ignored and treated just like ordinary white space. You need to add HTML tags to the text to convey the formatting you want or you could wrap it up in a pre tag as that will display it "as is".

As mentioned by others in the comments above, your use of `@_` doesn't make sense. And it doesn't really make sense for `$html_body` to be treated like an array either when all you're doing is appending HTML to it. So I've rewritten that chunk of code to use it as a scalar and append the HTML to it instead. And also fixed some mistakes in the HTML as you need to close tags in the same order as you open them.

```
print MAIL "Subject: Important Announcement \n";
print MAIL "\n"; # Need a blank line after the header to show it's finished
my $html_body = "<html><body>";
$html_body .=  "<h1><b><font color="red"><u>ATTENTION!</u></font></b></h1>";
$html_body .= "<pre>";
$html_body .= join("", @row);
$html_body .= "</pre>";
$html_body .= "</body></html>";
print MAIL $html_body;
close(MAIL);
```

Comment: Works great... Thanks a lot @Chris Turner

Comment: @SharmilaSubramaniam If you're accepting this answer, a tick would be appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all `@_` is an arrayof arguments passed to subroutines, and it looks like you're not in one. So, doing:

```
my ($body) = @_;
my ($html_body) = @_;
```

is setting `$body` & `$html_body` to `$_[0]`, which is `undef`.

How to fix?

---

There are two ways if you wrap it in a subroutine:

Use `shift` -> Which will make the above code look like:

```
my ($body) = shift;
my ($html_body)= shift;
```

Or,

```
my ($body, $html_body) = @_;
```

I would recommend the last one because it is less code and is more readable than the first one.

Comment: Except that there is nothing in `@_` because there is no subroutine.

Comment: Oops, Thanks for pointing out. Will update the answer accordingly.